# Converting To String Removes 0's after Decimal

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am copying data from a source workbook to a destination workbook by using the `Implode()` method below.  The issue that I have is that in the source workbook the format will be `7.00` but in the destination workbook the format will be `7`, I believe this is due to `CStr(MyR(1, i))` i.e. ConvertToString.  How can I alter this method so that if the column is in a `numeric` format that once it is copied to the destination workbook, it is once again in a `numeric` format?

```
Private Function Implode(ByVal R As Range, Optional ByVal D As String = strSeparator) As String
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, str As String, MyR() As Variant
    MyR = R
    For i = 1 To R.Columns.Count
        isPercent = False
        If iPC > 0 And IsNumeric(MyR(1, i)) And MyR(1, i) <> "" Then
            For ii = 1 To iPC
                If i = PercCols(ii) Then
                    isPercent = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ii
        End If
        str = CStr(MyR(1, i))
        If InStr(1, str, D) > 0 Then str = """" & str & """"
        If i = 1 Then
            Implode = str
        Else
            Implode = Implode & D & str
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try

```
 If IsNumeric(MyR(1, i)) Then 'Check for numeric
      Round(CDec(MyR(1, i)),2)
 Else
      CStr(MyR(1, i))
 End If
```

`CDec` allows those without decimal to be displayed as whole numbers

[More Info on Conversion Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: I thought about that, but I do not want every colomn to be CDbl - I only want  it to be CDbl if it has a decimal in the source workbook.

Comment: hi use CDec instead

Comment: CDec will keep string if string value and keep decimal if decimal value?

Comment: NonNumeric is a thing thay could be of use :D

Comment: yup, if your MyR(1, i) contains non numeric then you might want to check whether it is numeric first then set the conversion accordingly

Comment: Ah - yes I should have clarified - most the columns will contain text values, however there are roughly 6 that will contain a decimal value.